# Can I play a demo of Katamari Damacy on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, katamari-damacy

I would like to try playing Katamari Damacy but do not have Nintendo. Is there a demo version, even a short one, that runs on Windows 10?
I checked the [official site](https://www.bandainamcoent.com/games/katamari-demacy-reroll) but did not find any Windows demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there ist no demo of Katamari Damacy available for the PC, only for the Nintendo Switch. To test the game on PC, you could buy it on [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/848350/Katamari_Damacy_REROLL/) and return it within the refund time period, if you don't like it.